# How to retrieve web methods and its parameters from WSDL document using LINQ

Tags: c#-4.0, wsdl

I Have a WSDL document. I need to retrieve all the methods and its parameters for a requirement. I suggest any help regarding this will be very helpful to me.

Thank You, 
Sai Hariharan.K

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps: [WsdlImporter Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms522318.aspx)

Comment: We normally like answers to contain more then a single link to a page.

Comment: We normally also like questions to give some more relevant information. With the info available, there's not much more to be answered. Having said that, since it's no definitive answer it should've been a comment.

Comment: @Niels, apparently I'm only reputable enough to comment on my answers. And, as you said, there's not much to work on with the question, so I thought this was answer enough.

Comment: first of all i would like to thank to ppl who responded. second of all its truly unfair to undervote the question whom so ever did. No one is 100% perfect here for sure and for a novice all are equal for help. try to think in that way. More over it might be useful line given by Paulo ... I think you can present it in a good way explaining in detail how it is going to be done.